# magento 2 get password with Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I need an Observer to get all customer data after registration. II created an Observer for *customer_register_success* event and I see some data. But I need also the password, because next step is to send all data to another server.

I tried also to make the same with *customer_customer_authenticated*  event, which is used by UpgradeCustomerPasswordObserver, but the result of ***getData('password')*** is always null?

Can someone explain where's the trick?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a security measure. Password in plain text should never be available.

Comment: @vitoriodachef in this case, how the UpgradeCustomerPasswordObserver use this event? Or it's permitted for core modules?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... seems that the issue was in cache. After I disabled the cache I'm sure that the password can be retrieved from the event parameter or request parameters (depend of which functionality we need).